# Nix: what's the concrete difference between nixpkgs and nixpkgs.pkgs?

Tags: nix

In:

```
n = import <nixpkgs> {};
```

`n` contains an attribute `n.pkgs`, which also seems to contain all the available packages. What's the difference then between `n` and `n.pkgs`?

It seems it's related to the fixpoint semantics of Nix configuration and the availability to override some packages from nixpkgs, but I can't really wrap my head around it and find a clear distinction.

Comment: Nice to see two answers citing any sources that contradict each other...

Comment: @toraritte, ...though it's useful that one of those answers provides steps to run a test that refutes the other's claims.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`import <nixpkgs> {}` gives you a pristine instance of Nixpkgs, i.e. without any user-configuration applied.

`(import <nixpkgs> {}).pkgs` gives you a version of Nixpkgs that has user-configured settings and overrides from `~/.nixpkgs/config.nix` applied.

Comment: So that means within a nix-shell, you can acquire new packages expressions specified inside the ~/.nixpkgs/config.nix.

Comment: @PeterSimons Perhaps you might update this in a manner consistent with the test proposed by clacke's competing answer?

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between them. If you put this in your `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix`:

```
{
  packageOverrides = self: { newAttr = "testing testing"; };
}
```

... you'll see that these two commands have the same output:

`$ nix-instantiate --eval -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; newAttr'
"testing testing"
$ nix-instantiate --eval -E 'with import <nixpkgs> {}; pkgs.newAttr'
"testing testing"`

This is true for Nix 2.1.3 as well as for Nix 1.11.16.

The purpose of the `pkgs` alias inside nixpkgs is so that `callPackage` can fill in the `pkgs` parameter for a nix function that requires it.